# Cannot shell out to find command

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I want to shell out the following `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \;
```

I have tried many permutations of this command:

- `system("find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \;")`
- `` `find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \;` ``
- `%x(find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \;)`

But when I run the command, `find` generates the error message:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

I don't think the issue is characters which need to be escaped. This is probably a really simple fix, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is "shell out"?

Comment: Escape the backslash: `%x(find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \\;)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need - as @mudasobwa indicated - actually pass the backslash to the *find* command. If you try your string in irb, you see immediately what's going wrong:

```
>> "find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \;"
=> "find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . ;"
```

However, for actually running your find command, you need to make up your mind, whether `system` or `%x()` is the right tool to use. If you want do process the stdout of the command, you have to use `%x`, and in this case, you have to escape the backslash, because the string is then expended as if it were a string between double quotes:

```
find_stdout = %x(find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec mv {} . \\;)
```

If you are not interested in the result, but only in the overall success (exit code,....) of the command, you shhould use `system`, and in this case, you could use a single quoted string, which permits you to not escape the backslashes:

```
result = system('find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec mv {} . \;')
```

Of course, escaping here is not wrong either, and some people recommend for consistency and maintainability to always escape a backslash.